# Saving an object to custom state deletes complex parameters (Azure Bot Service)

Tags: azure-bot-service

Basicly I:

1. save the an object to a custom state
2. wait for the user response
3. load the obeject out of the state

The loading in generall works, but the object normally contains parameters like a "category" object which is now null. All primitive parameters like string or int are there and all complex parameters are now null.

Using Azure Bot Services v4.

Comment: Can you add code snippets for how you are saving the data? You're likely missing `await this.conversationState.saveChanges(context);`

Comment: I'm allready doing that. And that wouldn't explain why primitive variables work and complex not?

Comment: What SDK are you using - Node of C#?

Comment: I'm using .Net Core

Comment: I would recommend taking a look at this [sample](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/master/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/44.prompt-users-for-input/Bots/CustomPromptBot.cs) that save a userProfile - a complex parameter - to userState.

Comment: As you still having an issue with this?

Comment: We were not able to resolve this. But due to time constraints we did a workaround. We are reloading all complex parameters from the database when loading from the state. It's not beautiful but it worked.

Comment: I had the same issue. The scenario I had was when I was saving a complex object into the state and which had complex properties. When I would kid the object back out of the state the properties would be null. I ended up making properties in the state object for each of the complex properties that were children of the parent object I tried to pass through earlier.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding [JsonPropery] to all the properties